# Как изменить видимость кнопки в одной активности через другую активность?

Tags: java, button

Есть у меня две активности - Activity1 и Activity2. Activity1 - просто пустой лист с невидимой кнопкой button(невидимость её задана через xml-разметку).Код активности представлен ниже.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lessons);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Что следует написать в Activity2, в которой есть проверка нижепреведенного условия, вместо точек,чтобы кнопка в Activity1 стала видимой? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
if (a[0] >4*x[0]){
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Запиши в shared preferences нужное значение и читай в первой активити

Comment: еще есть такой механизм взаимодействия между активити, как startActivityForResult()->onActivityResult() - вызываете вторую активити первым методом и при закрытии ее в колбэк первой отправляете результат - делать ее кнопку видимой или нет

Comment: @axmed2004, а не могли бы вы расписать поподробнее ? К сожалению,не сталкивался с shared preferences.